# Region id is required field error

Tags: magento2, error, country-regions

In my **account page** after fillup all form fields, getting an error "`regionid is required field`" but I can't find out actual reason why this error comes every time. if anyone has idea please reply me.

Comment: Try to set this config in admin `Stores > Configuration > General > General, State Options`: 
`State is Required for : remove all selected country.`
`Allow to Choose State if It is Optional for Country : Set it to No`

Comment: @Prince:Is not working